# Installing ElasticSearch on Live server from cpanel. Shared Hosting

Tags: elasticsearch, installation

i am quite new to elasticsearch and have been experimenting on it quite a bit. I have elastic search installed on my windows and have make a small web application.

Now i want to move it to live server. I have cpanel with me how can i install the elasticsearch on the server and transfer my local elasticsearch data to live server??

On ELK stack i didnt find much.

Thanks

Comment: on which operating system you want to install Es

Comment: @OpsterElasticsearchNinja the server is linux.